# atan2 and Cardan angles - Problem with sign

Tags: trigonometry, education, classical-mechanics

I'd like to get the three Cardan angles starting from the below matrix and by using the function [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2). The problem is that I get two conflicting results.

[image]

where $- \pi/2 \le \beta \le \pi/2$.

If I consider the case $x>0$ in the above Wikipedia's webpage, I'll get (I call $R_{ij}$ the elements of the matrix):

$$ \tan(\gamma) = -\frac{R_{31}}{R_{33}} $$

and I can use one of these two $\operatorname {atan2}.$

Case 1: $x=R_{33}>0$

$$ \gamma = \operatorname {atan2}(-R_{31},R_{33}) = \arctan(\tan(\gamma)) = \gamma $$

if $R_{33}>0$.

Case 2:  $x=-R_{33}>0$

$$ \gamma = \operatorname {atan2}(R_{31},-R_{33}) = \arctan(\tan(\gamma)) = \gamma $$

if $-R_{33}>0$.

How it is possible to get the same result the first time when $R_{33}>0$, the second time when $-R_{33}>0$?

Maybe I can pass from $\tan$ to $\operatorname {atan2}$ only when there is no sign before the ratio between the numerator and the denominator of the right term $\tan(\text {angle})=\dfrac {\text {numerator}}{\text {denominator}}$?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: As $\cos \beta>0$, you always have that $(\cos γ,\sinγ)\sim (R_{33},-R_{31})$ so that always $γ=\arg(R_{33}-iR_{31})=atan2(-R_{31},R_{33})$.

Comment: Hello @LutzL, can you tell me why you wrote $(\cos γ,\sinγ)\sim (R_{33},-R_{31})$ instead of $(\cos γ,-\sinγ)\sim (R_{33},-R_{31})$ please?

Comment: Because there is only one sign to distribute. As I said, $\cosβ>0$ and $(\cosγ,\sinγ)=(R_{33},−R_{31})/\cosβ$. This defines the polar decomposition uniquely.

Comment: @LutzL thank you for your extremely clear explanation.

Comment: 1. So what do you find confusing here exactly? Why are you expecting different results in two chains of equalities that both start with $\gamma$? As it is, it is unclear what you are asking. 2. How is $\gamma$ defined, and what is its domain? You know that $\arctan(\tan\gamma)=\gamma$ does not hold in general, right?

Comment: Hello @FedericoPoloni, 1. my doubt arires from the fact that in both the above cases I get γ, but with conflicting conditions. 2. I forgot to write that the range of γ is (−π/2,π/2). Thank you for the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio $\frac{\sin \gamma}{\cos\gamma}$ does not specify an angle $-\pi < \gamma \leq \pi$ uniquely, but only up to $\pi$; to specify it, you need two coordinates $x,y$, not both zero, through which the variable side of the angle passes: that's the whole idea behind `atan2` and you should make sure you are familiar with it before tackling these computations.

In your case, you have restricted to $-\frac\pi2 < \gamma < \frac\pi2$, which means that your angle is in the right half-plane, so these coordinates have $x>0$. Focus on the first equal sign in each of those two alternative computations: only one of them is correct, the one with $\cos\gamma > 0$. To know which one it is, you will have to know the sign of $\cos \beta$ as well.